# Show that the Frobenius norm cannot be induced by two vector norms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-norms

Given a matrix space $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, a vector norm $\|\cdot\|_p$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and a vector norm $\|\cdot\|_q$ in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ with $p,q \ge 1$. The matrix norm induced by the two vector norms is defined as $$\| A \|_{p,q} = \sup{\frac{\|Ax\|_q}{\|x\|_p}}$$
The Frobenius norm is defined as $$\| A \|_F = \sqrt{\sum_{i,j} a_{ij}^2}$$
I want to prove that the Frobenius norm cannot be induced by any two vector norms. It is an old question though. I tried to follow the idea in [Algebraic Pavel's solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1245479/is-the-frobenius-norm-induced-by-two-vector-norms), but found out that it is not quite trivial to show that the two vector norms are unitarily invariant. Here is my attempt:

Suppose the Frobenius norm is induced by $\|\cdot\|_p,\|\cdot\|_p$. Since the Frobenius norm has unitary invariance property, so for any orthogonal matrix $P,Q$, $$ \sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|Ax\|_q}{\|x\|_p}=\|A\|_F=\|PAQ\|_F=\sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|PAQx\|_q}{\| x\|_p}=\sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|PAx\|_q}{\|Q^T x\|_p}$$ Then I want to show that $(p,q)$ that satisifies these equalities for any orthogonal $P,Q$ can only be $(2,2)$. Since we can fix one of $P,Q$ to be an identity matrix, it suffices to show the following statement:

If for any orthogonal matrix $Q$, any matrix $A$ and any $q\ge 1$, it holds that $$ \sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|Ax\|_q}{\|x\|_p}=\sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|Ax\|_q}{\|Q x\|_p}$$
then $p$ must be $2$.

The difficulty I met when proving this statement is that I cannot ignore the numerator and say $\sup_{x\neq 0}\|x\|_p=\sup_{x\neq 0}\|Q x\|_p$ immediately. Could somebody help? Thank you very much.